# How to implement the iPhone iOS8 create new email animation

Tags: ios, animation

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vfP5IqarJAA . 
I just wonder how should I implement the iOS8 on iPhone 's new an email's animation . 
It likes the old view controller sink behind and the new view controller appear.Like showing in the video .Any suggest will be grateful

Answer (score 1):

I've created a really easy and flexible version to implement it. Please take a look: https://github.com/galmarom/MultiActionsTableViewCell

If you interested I can give you a quick explanation of how to improve it. 
The advantage of it is that it works for iOS7 as well. 
If you programming only for iOS8 you can take a look at the following function
-(NSArray *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

Comment: I don't think this is what OP is asking for. He is asking about moving original view controller back and making it smaller, and not cell slide to reveal buttons.

Comment: If he wants to do it in iOS it is done at the function  -(NSArray *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

My program is a base for multi action buttons - so it's a suggestion- as he was asking.

Comment: No it's not. He is not asking animation inside the cell

Comment: No,I'm not asking the animation inside the cell. I just want to know when click the bottom new email button , then the old view controller go behind ,and present new view controller .just like the vidio at about 1:06 .

Comment: @唐余猛 : Have you found any solution to implement it? I also want the same thing in my app. If you found any helpful thing then please mention here.

Comment: @唐余猛 : I have also posted question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33050541/implement-animation-like-iphone-default-mail-app-compose-mail .You can answer there too if done.