# Implement animation like iPhone default mail app compose mail

Tags: iphone, xcode, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I want to implement animation like iphone default mail app while clicking on compose mail button the animation of background and foreground view in my app. Please see attached image below.

[image: Animation]

I am totally new about this animation.Please help me implementing it. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this ,

https://github.com/lukegeiger/LGSemiModalNavController

Happy coding, Cheers :D